# How to use Images outside of webapp in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Website. My website have a lot of Images. I want to place all my Image in a folder like 'C:/myimages' (Outside of webapp). How can I map:

> /myimages/abc.jpg ==> C:/myimages/abc.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: You can use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy the images to the server path from the local path. or you need to expose your folder as server(SimpleHTTPServer from python) and add proxy to webpack to serve the images.Also we cannot answer without knowing much about your configuration and how your running your server. Anyway image should be served from server not from local path.

Comment: Your website cant do that, if you have a server you could. but you dont have filesystem access in your frontend code

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias in your /public folder (if you are using CRA for example) that refers to C:/myimages/. Than you will be able to ask /abj.jpg.
If you are using a server, it can be done easily but it depends on the server (node, nginx, etc ....).

Hope this helps!